# how to send data to topic endpoint in a azure event grid from node js

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-eventgrid

How to send data to topic endpoint in a azure event grid from NodeJS

I have a topic created in a azure event grid. I need to send SMS message data to it from NodeJS Api call. How can I send it from NodeJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can use the `` Npm package where you create the event grid client  and then publish client to event grid.
- but first you will need the endpoint and access key . For endpoint you can get in the `overview` section
  [image]

and you can get the access key in `accesskey` tab

[image]

you can use the following code to publish the event using the event grid client and publish function

code:

```
var  uuid = require('uuid').v4;
var  msRestAzure = require('ms-rest-azure');
var  eventGrid = require("azure-eventgrid");
var  url = require('url');
  

function  EventGridSample() {
// TODO: Enter value for topicKey

let  topicKey = '<your AccessKey>';

// TODO: Enter value for topic-endpoint

let  topicEndPoint = '<Your Endpoint >';

  


let  topicCreds = new  msRestAzure.TopicCredentials(topicKey);
let  eventGridClient = new  eventGrid(topicCreds);

let  topicUrl = url.parse(topicEndPoint, true);

let  topicHostName = topicUrl.host;

let  currentDate = new  Date();

// the event which will be sent
let  events = [
{
id:  uuid(),
subject:  'Door1',
dataVersion:  '2.0',
eventType:  'Contoso.Items.ItemReceivedEvent',
data: {
itemSku :  'ContosoItemSku'
},
eventTime:  currentDate
}
];

eventGridClient.publishEvents(topicHostName, events).then((result) => {
    return  Promise.resolve(console.log('Published events successfully.'));
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log('An error ocurred ' + err);
});
}
EventGridSample();
```

[image]